# R Script - 3D Surface via Interpolation of several X,Y,Z points

Tags: r, interpolation, terr

I would like to use R and have it consume the few X,Y,Z points of data that I have (the black dots in the image) and then generate 300x300 XYZ points that would represent the 3D Surface Plot seen colored in the image.  I would like the output to simple be three columns, the X,Y, and Z points.  I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to generate the data I need.  I need the X,Y,Z points to generate an image in another program (spotfire) and do not need to do any graphics in R.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

[3D Surface Plot with Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4o5k.png)

```
> require(akima)
> points = read.csv("points.csv", header = TRUE)
> print(points)
         x       y    z
1   400.01  650.01 2.70
2   150.00  780.00 3.40
3   250.00  780.00 3.10
4   800.00  700.00 1.00
5  1000.00  680.00 1.00
6  1500.00  680.00 0.75
7  1700.00  700.00 1.00
8  1700.00  790.00 1.25
9  1600.00 1000.00 1.20
10 1750.00 1000.00 1.00
11 1800.00 1650.00 0.60
12 1400.00 1650.00 0.65
13 1000.00 1650.00 0.80
14  500.00 1650.00 0.90
15  150.00 1650.00 1.30
16  150.00 1050.00 3.90
17  500.00 1000.00 3.00
> s=interp(points$x,points$y,points$z,xo=seq(min(points$x),max(points$x),length=300),yo=seq(min(points$y),max(points$y),length=300))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I think all you need to do is transform the final list into a matrix.

```
s1 <- interp2xyz(s)
dim(s1)
# [1] 90000     3
```

A lot of points generate a NA values for z value

```
sum(is.na(s1[,3]))
# [1] 4897
```

You might choose to exclude those points or use extrapolation.